# After Reseting Admin Password of JFrog Jenkins build getting failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

After the reset the admin user password of JFrog artifactory jenkins build are failing with below errors.

1) Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

2) Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact woodstox:wstx-asl:pom:3.2.8 from/to shc-central (http://hostname:ip/artifactory/libs-release): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.

Comment: improved formatting for better reading.

Comment: Is there an actual question being asked? You changed the admin password in jfrog, then Jenkins failed with Unauthorized - aka bad username/password. Guessing you are using admin to upload something to jfrog. Seems like a correct response. ps: you should set up a separate user to deploy artifacts, not "admin"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct, any suggestion how i can generate the encrypted password for the admin user and where to put that pass, i mean in which file at jenkins/maven end.

Comment: Hello Guys, the issue got resolved i had change the anonymous user permission in the JFrog artifactory. thanks

Comment: Seems like you are deploying with anonymous user? hope you know what you are doing... Seems like you opened your Artifactory instance to everyone who have network access to the machine.

Comment: to add to what gba said, there are other ways to decouple users and their password from the build tools - like using access tokens (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/ACC/Access+Tokens).
Regardless, make sure you manage permissions to your artifacts with care. allowing deploying for anonymous users means everyone can deploy anything to your servers.

Comment: Thanks much guys for your valuable inputs, definitely allowing anonymous users is not a good idea, what i think, there should be a specific user for the respective projects.